# downloading a file once and playing it multiple times

Tags: shell-script, download

I want to play youtube videos on a loop from my terminal using mplayer, and for that I've written the following code taking pieces from here and there:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $(echo $*) ]]; then
    searchterm="$*"
else
    read -p "Enter the video ID: " searchterm
fi

searchterm=$(echo $searchterm | sed -e 's/\ /+/g')

video=$(youtube-dl -g https://youtube.com/v/$searchterm)

while true; 
do 
    mplayer $video
    sleep 2; 
done
```

To play the video you need to feed the video ID to the script. For example if this is the video you're watching: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=daQhI1JFXn4 Then the video ID is the part after `v=` which is `daQhI1JFXn4`

Everything works fine, except it still downloads the video every time that it goes trough the loop. I am wondering if there is any way that this could be changed so that it downloads the file only once and play it over and over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found `avplay` (you can replace with `ffplay` if you prefer) worked better for this, but I've left it as mplayer. `tee`-ing it to a file and piping to play the first time works. I've added a check to see if it's previously been downloaded.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $(echo $*) ]]; then
    searchterm="$*"
else
    read -p "Enter the video ID: " searchterm
fi

searchterm=$(echo $searchterm | sed -e 's/\ /+/g')

video=$(youtube-dl -g https://youtube.com/v/$searchterm)

[[ -f $searchterm.mp4 ]] || wget -O - $video 2>/dev/null | tee $searchterm.mp4 | mplayer -

while true; 
do
    sleep 2;
    mplayer $searchterm.mp4
done
```

Comment: Great. that `wget` is what I needed. But I avoided avplay or ffplay, since I can't find them on fedora repositories, and I still used mplayer. Is there any way that I can stop wget from showing all those contents that it's downloading?

Comment: You can still use `mplayer` , but you might need the `-cache` option to get it to work right. `wget`has the output on stderr (just realised it's not weird, it's so we can do exactly what we're doing), so  adding `2> /dev/null` to the command should do the trick for hiding the output. I'll put that in the answer.

Comment: perfect. thanks. mplayer works fine for me. But I keep that in mind if something goes wrong. Thanks. now only if I can search in the folder so that I don't download the same file if I have downloaded it before, I'll be set for life.

Comment: You could name the file $searchterm.mp4, instead of current.mp4, and check for its existence before running wget. I'll update the script with to match what you've asked for.

Comment: Thanks, I've done the naming, I'm not sure about how to search for its existence. I'm pretty new.

Comment: Updated to add a check. The || syntax is an OR. It means either there's a file called $searchterm.mp4, OR run the wget command.

Comment: Ah, this is beautiful, thank you very much. I had no idea there is something like ||. I really appreciate this. I should learn some more shell scripting. Sounds like fun

Answer (score 1):

Store the output of YouTube-dl in a file by redirecting. Instead of saving the command itself in the video variable.